# Error In XSLT code in passing param?

Tags: xml, xslt

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:str = "http://exslt.org/string" extension-element-prefixes="str">
<xsl:template name="padding">
   <xsl:param name="padChar" select="' '"/>
   <xsl:param name="padVar"/>
   <xsl:param name="length"/>
   <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="$length > string-length($padVar) ">

         <xsl:call-template name="padding">
           <xsl:with-param name="padChar" select="$padChar"/>
           <xsl:with-param name="padVar"  select="concat($padVar,$padChar)"/>
           <xsl:with-param name="length" select="$length"/>
         </xsl:call-template>

     </xsl:when>
     <xsl:otherwise>
       <xsl:value-of select="substring($padVar,1,$length)"/>
     </xsl:otherwise>
   </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>

<xsl:param name="member" />
<xsl:template match = "/">
    <xsl:for-each select="record/transaction">
        <transaction>
        <!--        <xsl:template match="member">
                    <xsl:call-template name="padding"/>
                </xsl:template>-->
                <xsl:template match = "date">
                    <xsl:call-template name="padding">
                        <xsl:with-param name = "padVar">20</with-param>
                        <xsl:with-param name = "length">50</with-param>
                <!--    <xsl:value-of select = "str:align(date,str:padding(100))"/> -->
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:template>
                <type>
                    <xsl:value-of select = "type"/>
                </type>
                <amount>
                    <xsl:value-of select = "amount"/>
                </amount>
                <remark>
                    <xsl:value-of select = "remark"/>
                </remark>
            </transaction>  
        </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am not able to detect an error in the above code. Can anybody please help?

I think the error is in the line where I am passing param name when I call the template. Also, can someone please share a link where can I learn about XSLT parameters?

Comment: What are the symptoms exactely? Provide a sample input XML as well.

Comment: The error may come from the `<xsl:param name="member" />`. It either must be inside an `<xsl:template>` or at a topmost position in the stylesheet (before all the `<xsl:template>` tags).

Comment: The error is almost certainly because you have `<xsl:template match = "date">` embedded within another template match ( `<xsl:template match = "/">` ). This is not allowed as templates must be direct children of the stylesheet element. If you want to know how to change your XSLT to get it to work, we would really need to see your input XML, and your expected output, and for you to explain exactly what you are trying to achieve. Thank you!

Comment: @potame top-level param elements don't have to be ahead of the templates, the only requirement is that they are direct children of the `xsl:stylesheet`

Comment: What XSLT processor are you using? A decent command line tool like Saxon often has helpful advice if something goes wrong, e.g. "`xsl:template` not allowed inside `xsl:template`".

Comment: @Ian Roberts thank you for your precision. It seems indeed that only the `<xsl:import>` must appear before all other top-level elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running this with Saxon: First attempt produces

```
Error on line 33 column 61 of test.xsl:
  SXXP0003: Error reported by XML parser: The element type "xsl:with-param" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</xsl:with-param>".
```

Fixing this produces:

```
Error at xsl:template on line 31 column 46 of test.xsl:
  XTSE0010: An transaction element must not contain an xsl:template element
Error at xsl:template on line 31 column 46 of test.xsl:
  XTSE0010: Element xsl:template must be top-level (a child of xsl:stylesheet, xsl:transform, or xsl:package)
```

These are very basic errors, I would hope that you understand them. If you're not seeing error messages that explain the problem in these kind of terms, then perhaps you need to think about using a different development environment. For example, some people try to develop XSLT code by running it directly in the browser: that gives you hopelessly unusable diagnostics when you get things wrong.